# Intellij broken SBT, cannot create new projects

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I created a Scala play 2 project and it worked fine, but the IDE found all sorts of issues in build.sbt. These errors didn't seem to affect anything, but I tried to fix them anyways. In doing so, I appear to have broken Intellij entirely and would like to start over.

I followed the instructions on [this page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-intellij-idea-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html) and re-setup the IDE, but now I cannot even properly create a Scala project.

[Creating a play project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4dxj.png) leads to a project with [no content root](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osMTV.png) and [no JDK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaTR9.png) even though I clearly specified one.

I found that the issue appears to be with SBT, and I managed to find the error in ~/Library/Logs/IntelliJIdea2017.1/sbt.last.log. What appears to be happening is that SBT encounters this error and the project is never completely loaded, and Intellij wasn't designed to expect errors here.

The error is

```
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/me/IdeaProjects/playtestagain/project
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sbt/TrackLevel
```

I cannot seem to find any information about this. I reinstalled SBT through homebrew and it didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: I just recently installed the Intellij CE including the SBT plugin (which does not come pre-installed but can be optionally selected during the Intellij installation) on my Mac. I have been developing SBT projects without issues for the last week or so.  I did not need to install SBT at all.  Try removing SBT installed via Homebrew and then remove and reinstall Intellij.

Comment: Which version of IDEA and scala plugin do you use? Support for Play 2.6 is added only in IDEA 2017.2, you may try Public Preview builds:
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/

Comment: That seems to be it. I can create a play 2.5.9 project just fine. Not sure why it gives you the option to select an unsupported version. Strangely the issue persisted in the EAP version though.

Comment: Also try setting your `sbt.version` to the latest in `project/build.properties` (eg: `sbt.version=0.13.15`).

Comment: Also note the separate (third-party) sbt plugin is not updated anymore and deprecated in favor of the builtin sbt support in the Scala plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that I was trying to use play 2.6 when it was not supported by IDEA. Selecting 2.5 rather than 2.6 works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on `Intellij 2017.2` and had serious problems using the `play-java-seed`. 
Using sbt `0.13.15`, i was able to open and build a play `2.6.6` project. Even activating the giter8 sbt plugin in `project/scaffold.sbt` and calling `g8Scaffold form`, as stated in the getting started guide, worked without any problems.